# Cannot get results from an object - Error saying does not exits

Tags: javascript, object

I have a function that returns an object. I want to be able to take out "results" from that object but I'm having difficulty. My error is

> 'results' does not exist on type 'SimulationResponse'.
> Property 'results' does not exist on type 'RelayResponseError'

The code is currently

```
    const response = await flashbotsProvider.simulate(
      simulateTransaction,
      blockNumber + 1
    );

    console.log(typeof response);
    console.log(response.results);
```

And if i only `console.log(response)` then the output is:

```
object
{
  bundleHash: '0x7765d8cf3063adb1bf9a2e524071a86ddcd3abf96acee689989f0a574073d9ac',
  coinbaseDiff: BigNumber { _hex: '0x02b959fc8d06f000', _isBigNumber: true },
  results: [
    {
      coinbaseDiff: '196287000000000000',
      ethSentToCoinbase: '0',
      fromAddress: '0xd612c9fBc4047E1cd50bf0996B8D277d0bF425F9',
      gasFees: '196287000000000000',
      gasPrice: '2100000000000',
      gasUsed: 93470,
      toAddress: '0x20EE855E43A7af19E407E39E5110c2C1Ee41F64D',
      txHash: '0x883597fc3df0e70bf78383c381394c6b39ca8f8cfe1885ad4b889f37339874dc',
      value: '0x'
    }
  ],
  totalGasUsed: 93470,
  firstRevert: undefined
}
```

any idea?

Comment: `response` could be one of two types. One of those types does not contain a `results` property, so it throws an error. You want to do something like `'results' in response ? response.results : null` (or however you want to handle the other case).

Comment: Could you elaborate more on that? Not following.

Comment: What is the type of `response`? Seems like it's a union of `RelayResponseError` and something else. Since `response` could be an error (which doesn't have the `results` property), you need to use an if statement to check the type. The easiest way to do that is to check if `'results' in response` since if response has the `results` property, then TypeScript know it's not the error type.

Comment: so after running ```console.log("results" in response ? response.results : "results are not in there");``` it does output the response - just like above

Comment: Yeah, presumably without the type error, yeah?

Answer (score 0):

if ("error" in response || response.firstRevert !== undefined) {
console.log(`Simulation Error: ${response}`);
process.exit(1);
}

I checked it if there is error, and when there is error you can get results by response.results.